# Can I tweak Jupyter Notebook to add two consecutive cells instead of one?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Every time we run a cell in the notebook, another empty cell gets created below it (**perfectly fine**)

But, can I somehow tweak it to add two consecutive cells because using shortcuts every time is a bit painful and I firmly believe it can be tweaked somehow like this:

- one *markdown* to write what I inferred from the previous executed cell's output and
- the *next* code cell as usual

Comment: When you run the markdown cell, is another cell not created?

Comment: Actually it's happening what I want  is to get 2 cells added simultaneously , one a markdown and a cell..

Comment: You can quickly change a cell to be a markdown cell by pressing `[Esc] m` then press enter to start typing.

Comment: I was looking for a tweak that will do that automatically for me as i nearly always write what i concluded...

Comment: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: Note that asking for "any link" is off-topic.

Comment: [Custom Keyboard Shortcuts.ipynb](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/blob/master/docs/source/examples/Notebook/Custom%20Keyboard%20Shortcuts.ipynb) demonstrates making custom keyboard shortcuts. You could also copy a pair of python and markdown cells and paste them